# How can I account for an optional property of a type using bracket syntax?

Tags: typescript

I'm quite new to Typescript and I'm trying to create a function where the query and response type changes depending on the path value.

```
function fetcher<
  P extends keyof paths,
  Q extends paths[P]["query"]
>(path: P, query?: Q): Promise<paths[P]["responses"]>{};
```

The issue I'm having is that some paths doesn't require/have a query and because of this I'm getting an error on `Q extends paths[P]["query"]`.

```
interface paths {
  "/somePath": {
    query: {
        // ...
    };
    response: {
        // ...
    };
  };
  "/someOtherPath": {
    response: {
        // ...
    };
  };
}
```

What I'm asking is if it's possible to do something like `paths[P]?["query"]`

Comment: You need to more clearly declare your `Paths` type. [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACACoyALNBvYNYtWaAZwAcB7ccigLjQCVplrYATAHnMlggBzADRo+A8IIB8AbiIkAjgFc4ATwD8TJeADW4agHdwwAL4gIMBCnRZc5AvOIBtHdFUNxQgLpNbOOWbAiOSq4Mho8NrIkKC0EdCQyDhw3PIYaNAAHjDgnPauqtTwmNg45MLyAIoZ2dC59n7kThheTgBEymptXsBSABSUpb6inbAaTJUAlL6w1AC2oPTcjc2tbWRUtPTk3VKEJKQJSrDgBBsAjEwA5Bs0dOi00FdmJjJAA)

Comment: @pilchard Alright, I suspected that. I wanted to kind of imbed the intellisense into the function itself, but I see why that could be troublesome. Thank you for the reply

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/blog/engineering/how-to-implement-autocomplete-with-javascript-on-your-website/ - you might be able to adapt this to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work around it by adding the query property to the path:

```
function fetcher<
  P extends keyof paths,
  Q extends (paths[P] & {
    query: {};
  })["query"]
>(path: P, query?: Q): Promise<paths[P]["responses"]> {}
```

Paths without the query property won't give an error if you give it a property now, but at least the ones who do work as intended.